# Is a server side hibernate query vulnerable to sql injection if it's string only is concatenated with ints?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, sql-injection

In this example the concat of the query strings is only done by inserting ints, is it still vulnerable ?

```
 public String void deleteUser(int id) {
        EntityManager em = HibernateUtil.createEntityManager();
        try {
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
            session.createQuery("delete from Users where id="+ id).executeUpdate();
            session.close();
            return "ok";
        }catch (Exception e){
            return null;
        }
    }
```

this function is called by a Rest Api.

Comment: Not really, no.  But it's still not an excuse to write it that way.

Comment: It is not clear from where you are getting your id from and what method you use to get it. If you exposed that in URL, then yes, it is vulnerable, otherwise no.

Answer (score 1):

If the id is coming from your code directly and not from an url/form/Ajax call, then it is safe. Otherwise, no.
Anyway, there's no harm in always protecting your parameter with setParameter()

```
session.createQuery("delete from Users where id = :id").setParameter("id", id).executeUpdate();
```

Comment: what about, only to understand it better and for curiosity ... is it possible to have an evil Int ?

Comment: My guess is "no". But all I'm saying is that you should get used to always protect parameters, so you won't wonder if there's a potentiel threat.

Anyway, you never know what can happen with code :)